# Why wrap GenericRowWithSchema using InternalRow in Dataset.collectFromPlan

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Look at `Dataset.collectFromPlan`

```
private def collectFromPlan(plan: SparkPlan): Array[T] = {
    val objProj = GenerateSafeProjection.generate(deserializer :: Nil)
    plan.executeCollect().map { row =>
      objProj(row).get(0, null).asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
```

the generated code for objProj is:

class SpecificSafeProjection extends org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BaseProjection {

```
  private Object[] references;
  private InternalRow mutableRow;
  private Object[] values;
  private org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType schema;

  public SpecificSafeProjection(Object[] references) {
    this.references = references;
    mutableRow = (InternalRow) references[references.length - 1];
    schema = (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) references[0];
  }

  public void initialize(int partitionIndex) {

  }

  public java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object _i) {
    ........
    final org.apache.spark.sql.Row value = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema(values, schema);
    if (false) {
      mutableRow.setNullAt(0);
    } else {

      mutableRow.update(0, value);
    }

    return mutableRow;
  }


}
```

And my question is:

The generated method `SpecificSafeProjection.apply` returns `mutableRow: InternalRow` who wraps `value:GenericRowWithSchema`, **why not return** `value:GenericRowWithSchema` **directly??**